# How do I make this function add Nothing to the list?

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to add Nothing to a list in a list comphrehension?

I have written the following function

```
toShape :: AltShape -> Shape
toShape ps = splitEvery (rowLength ps) 
            [ if (row `notElem` (map coords ps)) 
              then (lookup row (table ps)):r 
              else Nothing
               | row <- allCoords (colLength ps) (rowLength ps) ]
```

Where AltShape and Shape are defined as:

```
type AltShape = [Point]
data Point = P Colour (Int,Int)  deriving (Eq,Show)

type Shape = [Row]
type Row = [Square]
type Square = Maybe Colour

data Colour = Black | Red | Green   deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Basically the function is supposed to convert AltShapes to Shapes. I have been trying to accomplish this by creating a function which creates all possible coordinates based on the width and height of the shape, and then matching them to the actual points in the shape. If there is a match I want to add Just c to the list, where c is the colour, and if there isn't a match I want it to add Nothing to the list. But now I just end up with a list of Just c. How should I write it differently?

Comment: Um. Can you include enough code that we can reproduce your problem, please? Lots of stuff about this snippet looks off, but it's tough to tell for sure without knowing what `splitEvery`, `rowLength`, `coords`, `table`, `allCoords`, `colLength`, and `rowLength` do.

Answer (score 1):

Use guards

```
toShape :: AltShape -> Shape
toShape ps = splitEvery (rowLength ps) 
            [ (lookup row (table ps)):r 
            | row <- allCoords (colLength ps) (rowLength ps)
            , row `notElem` (map coords ps) ]
```